# Use NULL in default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, null, default-constructor

In my C++ class (header file), I am using this:

```
int pWholesalerId;
```

Now, I have made a default constructor. Is it possible to set the value of this attribute as null?

```
Game::Game()
{
    gId = 0;
    pWholesalerId = Null;
}
```

currently, I get `identifier "Null" is undefined` even though I am already using `#include <stddef.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There is no such thing as setting an `int` to null. `int`s are numbers. They are not "nullable".

You can consider dynamic allocation like `std::unique_ptr<int>` (though this is very heavy for an `int`) or `std::optional<int>`.

Alternatively, just keep your own tracking of whether the `int`'s value is "meaningful" or not (e.g. with a bool, or by examining some other aspect of your class's state). Setting it to `0` may or may not accomplish this goal, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In the C header `<stddef.h>` or in the C++ header `<cstddef>` there is no macro Null. There is defined the macro `NULL`. But it is used to initialize a pointer by a null pointer constant.

In your constructor you should just write

```
pWholesalerId = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write simply

```
int pWholesalerId = 0;
```

in the header file, with a similar statement for `gId`, then remove the default constuctor entirely.

`Null` is not defined by standard C++. `NULL` is but its meaning varies across C and C++ and is best avoided. Use `0` to assign to an `int`, and `nullptr` to assign to a pointer type.